# Rewriting and redirecting my urls with ? that has been indexed by google

Tags: php, codeigniter, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So here's how it is, i am using codeigniter for my website, and before theres always that index.php? on my every url or links, for example mysite.com/index.php?/about

Google has indexed all of my urls with that index.php? and i want to remove it and redirect it without that.
im having a problem rewriting the url and redirect it to mysite.com/about
and this what i have tried so far

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index\.php\?(/[^\s\?]+)? [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [QSA,L,R=301]
```

what happened is, it only removed the index.php, for example mysite.com/index.php?/about will turn to mysite.com/?/about i dont know how to remove that question mark,

Im not good on mod_rewrite thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index.php\?(/[^\s\?]+)? [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [QSA,L,R=301]

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/[a-z]+$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/index.php$ %{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L,R=301]
```